# Mapping Iterator into Iterator[Future] is not behaving as expecting

Tags: scala

Using Scala 2.13.0:

```scala
    implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.global
    val arr = (0 until 20).toIterator
      .map { x =>
        Thread.sleep(500);
        println(x);
        x
      }

    val fss = arr.map { slowX =>
      Future { blocking { slowX } }
    }
    Await.result(Future.sequence(fss), Inf)
```

### problem

`arr` is an iterator where each item needs 500ms processing time. We map the iterator with `Future { blocking { ... }}` with the purpose of making the processing parallel (using the global execution context). Finally we run `Future.sequence`
to consume the iterator.

Given the definition of `Future.apply[T](body: =>T)` and `blocking[T](body: =>T)`, `body` is passed lazily, which means that `body` will be processed in the Future. If we inject that in the definition of `Iterator.map`, we get `def next() = Future{blocking(self.next())}`, so each item of the iterator should be processed in the Future.

But when I try this example however, I can see that the iterator is consumed sequentially, which is not what is expected!

Is that a Scala bug?? Or am I missing something?

Comment: `arr.map` is computing the value in the previous `map` before it is passed to the `Future`, so the `sleep` is happening outside the `Future`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not a bug, because:

```
val arr = (0 until 20).toIterator
// this map invokes first and executed sequentially, because it executes in same thread.
      .map { x => 
        Thread.sleep(500);
        println(x);
        x
      }

    // This go sequentially because upstream map executed sequentially in same thread.
    // So, "Future { blocking { slowX } }" can be replaced with "Future.successfull(slowX)"
   // because no computation executed
    val fss = arr.map { slowX =>
      Future { blocking { slowX } }
    }
```

If you want perform completely asynchronously, you can do something like:

```
def heavyCalculation(x: Int) = {
  Thread.sleep(500);
  println(x);
  x
}

val result = Future.traverse((0 until 20).toList) { x => 
  Future(blocking(heavyCalculation(x)))
}

Await.result(result, 1 minute)
```

Working Scatie example: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/3v06NpypRHKYkqBgzaeVXg

Comment: `Iterator.map` doesn't have any action by itself: it is simply defining the output iterator. `sleep` is only called when the iterator gets consumed (by `Future.sequence`). If you follow the source code of `Iterator.map` you'll see that the body of the first map corresponds to `next()`, which is run within the Future.

Comment: @stackoverflowed Sorry, for misunderstanding, I was leading by your code example, if you can, please, provide in question more precise code example which you have problem with?. If you have Iterator with slow next method, what about `hasNext` method is it slow as well? is this iterator thread safe?

Comment: @stackoverflowed why do you have an `Iterator` that blocks on its `next`? Can you control the code that creates it?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez `blocking` does not block! It does just the opposite by telling the ExecutionContext: "This piece of code might be blocking on some IO, so please schedule another task while I am waiting". You can try to add `Future {...}` in the first map, then add `Future { blocking {...}}` and you will see a clear spead-up.

Comment: @stackoverflowed yes it doesn't block a compute thread but it blocks a thread, you can not take a blocking operation and make it non-blocking like magic. What `blocking` does is just telling the **EC** that the next chunk is a blocking operation so it can take an action, many **ECs** will just ignore that, the default one will create a new thread and run that function in that thread so it can keep a fixed number of compute threads. - That is why I said that you should be careful with that, because you may end up creating too many threads and starve memory.

Comment: @stackoverflowed Second the speed-up depends on the nature of each blocking task. If they are independent like a `sleep` sure, but if they related like your `next` then no. Because the next task will not start until the end of the previous one. Also, even if they are all independent, you have to consider the overhead of creating and switch threads to get the best speedup. And finally, you may need to balance this with your other _(hopefully CPU-bounded)_ work. - BTW, it may also be worth to consider if you want parallelism or if just simple asynchronism is enough and take care of concurrency.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez what do you mean with "it may also be worth to consider if you want parallelism or if just simple asynchronism is enough and take care of concurrency."?

Comment: @stackoverflowed parallelism, asynchronism and concurrency are three different _(although related)_ things; and many people confuse them due to their similarities. My point with that last phrase was to raise that concern, do you really want to take a bunch of blocking operations and execute them in parallel? Are you sure is even possible? - or you just want them to be executed in an asynchronous fashion and thus not blocking the main thread(s). And finally, either one you choose, you have to be careful with creating concurrency problems _(I couldn't add this last word in the previous message)_

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez it all makes sense now. Thanks for your answers as they got me to think and get a better picture.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not a proper benchmark, you actually haven't show formal proof that this is sequential and not parallel *(although is "obvious" from the source code that it isn't)*.

Second, and `Iterator` of `Futures` is probably a bad idea; at this point, it may make sense to look into a streaming solution like **Akka-Streams**, **fs2**, **Monix** or **ZIO**.

Third, what is even the point of having a bunch of `blocking` futures? you aren't actually winning too much.

Fourth, the problem is that the second `map` is not passing the block of the first `map`, just the result. So, you actually did the `sleep` before creating the `Future`.

Fifth, you probably want to do this instead.

```scala
val result = Future.traverse(data) { elem =>
  Future {
    blocking {
      // Process elem here.
    }
  }
}
Await.result(result, Inf)
```

Comment: `blocking` is precisely used so that the global execution context does not block ;)
See here https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html (The Global Execution Context)

Comment: @stackoverflowed that is my point, you are just creating a bunch of threads to block them. What is the point? not blocking the main thread? You are blocking it in the `Await` to wait for all the blocking to finish. To start all blocking operations asynchronously? Then you have to be careful with that because you could end up creating too many threads that you would starve your memory.

Comment: @stackoverflowed Also, that will only work if the iterator is capable of producing multiple elements in parallel, which it probably can't, so at the end, it will be slower than a serial execution because of the overhead of threads. Finally, even if it could you shouldn't be playing with mutability + concurrency this will only cause hard to debug errors. Use an appropriate concurrent abstraction _(like a **Stream**)_.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers were pointing in the right direction, but the formal answer is the following: the signature of `Iterator.map(f: A => B)` tells us that `A` that `A` is computed before `f` is applied to it (because it is not `=> A`). Therefore, `next()` is computed in the main thread.